# Generar una Alerta al presionar un botón dependiendo de las opciones de radio con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero hacer que las opciones muestren un mensaje dependiendo de la opción que se haya elegido. Tengo solamente el esqueleto y quisiera que en la primer opción de una alerta de "Hola". En la segunda opción quiero que el nombre que se haya escrito en el text box le aparezca el mensaje "Hola" + nombre.

Prácticamente quiero saber cómo se puede hacer llamar en JavaScript la opción que se haya escogido en los radios.

Esto es lo que tengo del código de HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript | JQuery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">  
</head>

<body>

    <script src="JS/myJS.js"></script>
    <div class="caja">
        <form id="formulario">
            Nombre: <input type="text" id="Nombre"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccionar" id="hola" value="A">Hola</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccionar" id="holaNombre" value="B">Hola "Nombre"</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccionar" id="cambioColor" value="C">Cambio de color</input><br>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccionar" id="Redireccionar" value="D">Redireccionar</input><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Ejecutar" onclick="...">
            <input type="submit" value="Formulario" onclick="...">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.caja form{
width: 200px;
height: 130px;
border: 2px solid blue;
padding: 35px;
border-radius: 25px;
margin: auto;
background-color: #ffffff;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias cosas en tu código que están raras. Por ejemplo, los input no tienen una etiqueta de cierre `</input>`.
Pero bueno, puedes hacerlo poniendo un evento `onchange` en las etiquetas de cada radio (Similar a lo que tienes en tu botones - `onclick`) donde el argumento que pasa es `this` osea el mismo radio al que estás seleccionando. Posterior, puedes preguntar si el radio que pasó tiene un Id `HolaNombre` Si es así concatenas lo que tenga escrito el `textbox`. Hay muchas formas de hacer este código, pero creo que esto te puede servir muy bien.

Saludos

```js
function radioChange( that ){
  let val = that.value;
  if( that.id == 'holaNombre' ){
    let nombre = document.getElementById('Nombre').value;
    alert( val + ' ' + nombre );
  }else{
    alert( val ); 
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
            Nombre: <input type="text" id="Nombre"><br>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccionar" onchange="radioChange(this);"id="hola" value="Hola">Hola<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccionar" onchange="radioChange(this);" id="holaNombre" value="Hola">Hola nombre<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccionar" onchange="radioChange(this);" id="cambioColor" value="Cambio de color">Cambio de color<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seleccionar" onchange="radioChange(this);" id="Redireccionar" value="Redireccionar">Redireccionar<br>
            <input type="submit" value="Ejecutar" onclick="...">
            <input type="submit" value="Formulario" onclick="...">
        </form>
```